# How do I make an Eigen Model Matrix for rotating a triangle around the z-axis

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, eigen3, projection-matrix

How do you create a model matrix for rotating a triangle around the Z-axis?

This is the current description of what I need to do:

The main tasks of this program include implementing a transformation matrix and a view/projection matrix. Giving three 3D points v0(2.0, 0.0, −2.0), v1(0.0, 2.0, −2.0), v2(−2.0, 0.0, −2.0),you are required to transform these points to the camera/view/monitor coordinates system, and draw a lined triangle based on them. In general, you are required to build a model, view, projection transformation matrix, so that we can display the lined triangle on the screen.

The current code that was given to me looks like this.

```
#include "Triangle.hpp"
#include "rasterizer.hpp"
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

constexpr double MY_PI = 3.1415926;

Eigen::Matrix4f get_view_matrix(Eigen::Vector3f eye_pos)
{
    Eigen::Matrix4f view = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity();

    Eigen::Matrix4f translate;
    translate << 1, 0, 0, -eye_pos[0], 0, 1, 0, -eye_pos[1], 0, 0, 1,
        -eye_pos[2], 0, 0, 0, 1;

    view = translate * view;

    return view;
}

Eigen::Matrix4f get_model_matrix(float rotation_angle)
{
    Eigen::Matrix4f model = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity();

    // TODO: Implement this function
    // Create the model matrix for rotating the triangle around the Z axis.
    // Then return it.

    return model;
}

Eigen::Matrix4f get_projection_matrix(float eye_fov, float aspect_ratio,
                                      float zNear, float zFar)
{
    // Students will implement this function

    Eigen::Matrix4f projection = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity();

    // TODO: Implement this function
    // Create the projection matrix for the given parameters.
    // Then return it.

    return projection;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    float angle = 0;
    bool command_line = false;
    std::string filename = "output.png";

    if (argc >= 3) {
        command_line = true;
        angle = std::stof(argv[2]); // -r by default
        if (argc == 4) {
            filename = std::string(argv[3]);
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }

    rst::rasterizer r(700, 700);

    Eigen::Vector3f eye_pos = {0, 0, 5};

    std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> pos{{2, 0, -2}, {0, 2, -2}, {-2, 0, -2}};

    std::vector<Eigen::Vector3i> ind{{0, 1, 2}};

    auto pos_id = r.load_positions(pos);
    auto ind_id = r.load_indices(ind);

    int key = 0;
    int frame_count = 0;

    if (command_line) {
        r.clear(rst::Buffers::Color | rst::Buffers::Depth);

        r.set_model(get_model_matrix(angle));
        r.set_view(get_view_matrix(eye_pos));
        r.set_projection(get_projection_matrix(45, 1, 0.1, 50));

        r.draw(pos_id, ind_id, rst::Primitive::Triangle);
        cv::Mat image(700, 700, CV_32FC3, r.frame_buffer().data());
        image.convertTo(image, CV_8UC3, 1.0f);

        cv::imwrite(filename, image);

        return 0;
    }

    while (key != 27) {
        r.clear(rst::Buffers::Color | rst::Buffers::Depth);

        r.set_model(get_model_matrix(angle));
        r.set_view(get_view_matrix(eye_pos));
        r.set_projection(get_projection_matrix(45, 1, 0.1, 50));

        r.draw(pos_id, ind_id, rst::Primitive::Triangle);

        cv::Mat image(700, 700, CV_32FC3, r.frame_buffer().data());
        image.convertTo(image, CV_8UC3, 1.0f);
        cv::imshow("image", image);
        key = cv::waitKey(10);

        std::cout << "frame count: " << frame_count++ << '\n';

        if (key == 'a') {
            angle += 10;
        }
        else if (key == 'd') {
            angle -= 10;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not looking for just the answer to the problem. I more or less want to understand what the code is saying and get an example of something similar to the code given to me. Looking through the internet has given me no luck. I can't seem to find other codes similar to this. I learn best off of examples.

I can provide the other programs that are included if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it yourself with the following code:

```
Eigen::AngleAxisf rotationVector(rotation_angle * MY_PI / 180, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ());
model = rotationVector.toRotationMatrix();
```